# Single sign-on authentication on Django and Grafana

Tags: python, django

I'm using `grafana iframes` in my HTML page running in k, but every time I open my page to view the embedded graphs I need to access `grafana` and thus login to authenticate my user, my `Django` application already has a login page, I would like to use only one login on my page and send a proxy request to `grafana`, so I do not need to perform two logins every time I open my application.

**View**

```
class GraphanaProxyView(ProxyView):
    upstream = 'http://172.30.3.141:3000/'

    def get_proxy_request_headers(self, request):
       headers = super(GraphanaProxyView, self).get_proxy_request_headers(request)
       headers['X-WEBAUTH-USER'] = request.user.username
       return headers
```

**Urls**

```
url(r'^grafana/(?P<path>.*)$', views.GraphanaProxyView.as_view(), name='graphana-dashboards'),
```

**Config Grafana**

```
grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - "./grafana/datastore:/var/lib/grafana"

    environment:
      - GF_SMTP_ENABLED=true  
      - GF_SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com:587
      - GF_SMTP_USER=user@domain.com.br
      - GF_SMTP_PASSWORD=password
      - GF_SMTP_FROM_NAME=Grafana Snipped
      - GF_SMTP_SKIP_VERIFY=true


      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_NAME=View
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=View
      - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false

      - GF_AUTH_PROXY_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_PROXY_HEADER_NAME = X-WEBAUTH-USER
      - GF_AUTH_PROXY_HEADER_PROPERTY=username       
      - GF_AUTH_PROXY_AUTO_SIGN_UP=true 
      - GF_AUTH_PROXY_LDAP_SYNC_TTL=60
      - GF_AUTH_PROXY_WHITELIST = 172.30.3.207
      - GF_SERVER_DOMAIN = 172.30.3.141
```

I'm getting this error when accessing URL:

> If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files

1. This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.
2. If you host `grafana` under subpath make sure your `grafana.ini` root_path setting includes subpath
3. If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: `npm run dev`, `npm run watch`, or `npm run build`
4. Sometimes restarting `grafana-server` can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you for contacting me by email also.

For the sake of completeness I re-post here the answered I have given to the original post in Stackoverflow Portugal: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/362727/autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-single-sign-on-django-e-grafana

Your report is almost complete, great!

Given the warning

`This setting is also important if you have a reverse proxy in front of Grafana that exposes it through a subpath. In that case add the subpath to the end of this URL setting.`

at http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/#root-url

a fault can be the setting of the `GF_SERVER_DOMAIN` envvar that should be replaced by the `GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=http://172.30.3.141:3000/` that holds the port (and this would mean a bug of Grafana documentation...)

If not this, only two other questions come to my mind to identify the issue:

1. does your request.user.username match the Grafana username?
2. what is the "src" attribute of your iframe? It must be `https://172.30.3.207/grafana/(dashboard path)`

beside this basic questions I suggest you to try to remove the `GF_AUTH_PROXY_WHITELIST` envvar and to try to authenticate via `curl` like:

`curl -H "X-WEBAUTH-USER: anthony" http://172.30.3.141:3000/api/user`

as you can find at http://docs.grafana.org/auth/auth-proxy/#interacting-with-grafana-s-authproxy-via-curl

Follows my Django view and my grafana config to reach the working result, but seen no meaningful differences:

```
class GraphanaProxyView(ProxyView):
upstream = 'http://localhost:8891/dashboard/'

def get_proxy_request_headers(self, request):
    headers = super(GraphanaProxyView, self).get_proxy_request_headers(request)
    headers['X-WEBAUTH-APP-USER'] = request.user.username
    return header
```

Grafana config:

```
[auth]
disable_login_form = true

[auth.proxy]
enabled = true
header_name = X-WEBAUTH-APP-USER
;header_property = username
;auto_sign_up = true
;ldap_sync_ttl = 60
whitelist = 127.0.0.1

[auth.basic]
enabled = false


[server]
protocol = http
http_addr = 127.0.0.1
http_port = 8891

domain = solomon.labs.befair.it
;enforce_domain = false
root_url = https://%(domain)s/ui/
```