# Nginx authenticate iframe

Tags: django, authentication, nginx, grafana

I am running a django app on a server and i am running grafana on a different server with nginx as a reverse proxy (grafana and nginx are on the same server).

I can manage to redirect an incoming URL and authenticate it via my backend, but I still get redirected to the grafana login screen, even when my django app sends a 200 response

My setup:

1. I am having a grafana server running under https with a nginx proxy. The nginx-setup

```
server {
    server_name  grafana.myserver.com;
     
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass           http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location ~ ^/iframe(.*)$ {
      auth_request /iframe-auth;
      set $iframe_url http://localhost:3000$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_pass $iframe_url;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    }

    location = /iframe-auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass https://blub.de/auth/check/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }

}
```

In the above I am using the nginx auth module to redirect the incoming URL from the iframe the my django backend server. Here I do the authentication which works fine. I tested this by printing out the URL and I am authenticating the user and I am returning a 200 response if authenticated.

Ok cool. I expected now that my iframe would show on my website. But no, it does not. Instead I get a redirect to the grafana login screen.

Can nginx even do what I want?

My grafana.ini config is standard, I did not change much, but I set the `auth.proxy` to enabled:

```
#################################### Auth Proxy ##########################
[auth.proxy]
enabled = true
;header_name = X-WEBAUTH-USER
;header_property = username
auto_sign_up = true
;sync_ttl = 60
;whitelist = XXX, XXX
;headers = Email:X-User-Email, Name:X-User-Name
# Non-ASCII strings in header values are encoded using quoted-printable encoding
;headers_encoded = false
# Read the auth proxy docs for details on what the setting below enables
;enable_login_token = false
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I read in the "[Grafana documentation / Set up / Configure security / Configure authentication / Auth proxy](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/auth-proxy/)"

```bash
# HTTP Header name that will contain the username or email
header_name = X-WEBAUTH-USER
```

In other words, for Grafana's auth proxy feature to work, it expects to see a specific header with the username in it. That header is defined by the `header_name` in the `grafana.ini` file.

But in your case, that `header_name` is commented out in your `grafana.ini` file. Also, there is no setting for `header_name` in your Nginx configuration. So, it is likely Grafana does not know *where* to look for the username... which makes it redirect to the login screen.

Try and add `header_name` back to the `grafana.ini` and set it to something like `X-WEBAUTH-USER` or any header name of your choice. See "[Single sign-on authentication on Django and Grafana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55039626/6309)" as an illustration.

Then, in your Nginx configuration (in the `/iframe` location block), you need to set this header with [`proxy_set_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) and pass it along to Grafana. Your Django app should return this header after a successful authentication, and Nginx should pick it up and pass it along.

```
server {
    server_name  grafana.myserver.com;
     
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass           http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location ~ ^/iframe(.*)$ {
      auth_request /iframe-auth;
      set $iframe_url http://localhost:3000$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_pass $iframe_url;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_set_header X-WEBAUTH-USER $http_x_webauth_user;
    }

    location = /iframe-auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass https://blub.de/auth/check/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }

}
```

You should replace `X-WEBAUTH-USER` and `$http_x_webauth_user` with the actual header name and value from the authenticated request if they are different.

The `proxy_set_header X-WEBAUTH-USER $http_x_webauth_user;` line tells Nginx to take the `X-WEBAUTH-USER` header from the incoming request and pass it along to Grafana.

Make sure that your Django app returns this header with the username after a successful authentication.
See for instance the Django view also mentioned in "[Single sign-on authentication on Django and Grafana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55039626/6309)" (already mentioned above).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and time - I will try this and report back